# How to add extra authentication header in $resource object in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

How to add extra two headers('Authentication', 'Valid Device') at the time of API request. I am defining the resource object as following

> $resource(apiObject.url, apiObject.paramDefaults, apiObject.actions,
>   apiObject.options);

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add headers for each `$resource` call, you can use `$http` (`$http` is used by `$resource`) interceptors.
I suggest you to take a look on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

On the other side, if you just need to add those headers for specific `$resource` calls, you can use the third argument of $resource (`apiObject.actions` in your case), and add a `headers` object to your method.

For example :

```
let apiObject = {
  actions: {
    save: { // Or any other method
      method: 'POST',
      cache: true,
      headers: {
        'Authentication': 'foo',
        'Valid Device', 'bar',
      },
      transformRequest: (data) => (
        // You can also add some logic here if you need to transform you request
        data
      ),
    }
  }
};

$resource(apiObject.url, apiObject.paramDefaults, apiObject.actions, apiObject.options);
```